# How to display a video in spotify advertise page?

Tags: spotify

I am new with the spotify app. I try to display a video in spotify's advertise page. However none of the things that I was trying work (jw player, flow player, youtube iframe. html5). Any hints?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Any external hosts with assets you request need to be added to the RequiredPermissions part of the app manifest:

http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#applicationmanifest

Answer (score -1):

In order to display a video in the spotify you have to fulfill following **requirements**:

- your video file has to be stored on the 3rd party server.
- you have to use open-source video player (e.g “JW Player”).
- you have to create a html file that will be your lightbox. This is the file that you will embed in the video file and player library.
- image file for background of the player.
- Destination URL must be open in new browser window.
- And don't forget to add the address of host your host to the **permissions** in spotify's **manifest** file!!!

**Example**: [here](http://themoonlightproduction.com/lukas/share/stoSpotify.html)